# Dispatching subclasses to their respective executor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

Java 11 and Spring Boot here (if that makes a difference). I have the following POJOs:

```
public abstract class AbstractFruit {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Integer quantity;
    // ...etc.
    // getters, setters & ctor omitted for brevity
}

public class Apple extends AbstractFruit {
    private AppleType appleType;
    // etc.
}

public class Pear extends AbstractFruit { ... }

public class Orange extends AbstractFruit { ... }

// etc., dozens more
```

And for each of these `AbstractFruit` subclasses, there is a respective `AbstractFruitExecutor` class that executes instances of that fruit:

```
public abstract class AbstractFruitExecutor<E extends AbstractFruit> {

    protected abstract void execute(FruitProcessingContext fpc, E fruit);

    // other stuff, omitted for brevity
}

public class AppleExecutor extends AbstractFruitExecutor<Apple> { ... }
public class PearExecutor extends AbstractFruitExecutor<Pear> { ... }
public class OrangeExecutor extends AbstractFruitExecutor<Orange> { ... }
```

I will be given a `List<AbstractFruit>` and need to send each element in the list to its respective executor:

```
@Service
public class FruitExecutionDispatch {

    @Autowired
    private Map<Class<? extends AbstractFruit>, AbstractFruitExecutor> fruitExecutorMap;

    public void executeAll(List<AbstractFruit> fruits, FruitProcessingContext fpc) {

        fruits.forEach(fruit -> {
            AbstractFruitExecutor<?> fruitExecutor = findFruitExecutor(fruit).orElseThrow();
            fruitExecutor.execute(fpc, fruit);
        });

    }

    private Optional<AbstractFruitExecutor<?>> findFruitExecutor(AbstractFruit fruit) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(fruitExecutorMap.get(fruit.getClass()));
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the above code produces a compiler error:

> "*Required type: capture of ?, Provided: AbstractFruit*"

The above is IntelliJ IDE error. On the command line when I try to run the app I get:

```
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends AbstractFruit from capture of ?
```

Can someone spot where I'm going awry and explain how I can fix this compiler error? Also if there are any better design patterns or utilities that Spring/Boot offers to help with this, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a compilation output?

Comment: Please see my updates @RomanC

Comment: Don't use raw types (not that adding a generic type will help here, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is caused by the fruitExecutorMap field being defined as a Map that can hold any AbstractFruitExecutor instance. When calling fruitExecutorMap.get(fruit.getClass()), the returned value is of an unknown type that extends AbstractFruit, causing a compatibility issue. To fix this, use a bounded wildcard for the fruitExecutorMap field to only accept AbstractFruitExecutor instances that can handle a specific subtype of AbstractFruit. This guarantees compatibility between the type of fruitExecutor and fruit, resolving the error.

```java
private Map<Class<? extends AbstractFruit>, AbstractFruitExecutor<? extends AbstractFruit>> fruitExecutorMap;
```

Alternate solution is to use Visitor Design pattern

```java
public interface FruitVisitor {
    void visit(Apple apple);
    void visit(Pear pear);
    void visit(Orange orange);
    // Add visit methods for other concrete subclasses of AbstractFruit as needed
}

public abstract class AbstractFruit {
    // ...
    public abstract void accept(FruitVisitor visitor);
}

public class Apple extends AbstractFruit {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void accept(FruitVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Pear extends AbstractFruit {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void accept(FruitVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Orange extends AbstractFruit {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void accept(FruitVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class FruitProcessingContext {
    // Define any context information needed for fruit processing
}

@Service
public class FruitExecutionDispatch implements FruitVisitor {

    @Autowired
    private FruitProcessingContext fpc;

    public void executeAll(List<AbstractFruit> fruits) {
        fruits.forEach(fruit -> fruit.accept(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Apple apple) {
        // Logic for processing an apple goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Pear pear) {
        // Logic for processing a pear goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Orange orange) {
        // Logic for processing an orange goes here
    }

    // Implement additional visit methods for other concrete subclasses of AbstractFruit as needed
}
```